# Issues with drawing images using multiple canvas's

Tags: html, drawing, html5-canvas

Drawing was working fine, until I decided to use multiple canvas's. I have a stage canvas, an entity canvas, and an object canvas. I'll probably end up combining the object and entity canvas's, though. Anyway, as you can see below, my hero class draws fine. I then tried to make an entity class with the same draw function, but it won't let me draw when I call the function. I have almost the same issue with my background canvas. I don't have a class for the background yet, but I will. But I try simply drawing the image with the stage's context, and it breaks the code.

(I tried setting up a JSFiddle, but I wouldn't be able to get the images on there.)

**UPDATE**
Half of my issue was fixed by markE. The only issue I currently have, is my entitiesCtx is the the only context that can draw images/rectangles. The other ctx's just can't draw anything. Help, please! I updated the code.

```
var stage = document.getElementById('stage');
var ctxStage = stage.getContext('2d');
var entitiesStage = document.getElementById('entities');
var ctxEntities = entitiesStage.getContext('2d');
var bg = document.getElementById('bg');
var ctxBg = bg.getContext('2d');
var playerImg = new Image();
playerImg.src = 'res/player_sprite_sheet.png';
var bgImg = new Image();
bgImg.onload = function() {
    ctxBg.drawImage(bgImg,0,0,80,50,-200,-90,1000,700);
};
bgImg.src = 'res/background.png';
var consoleImg = new Image();
consoleImg.onload = function() {
    ctxEntities.drawImage(consoleImg,0,0,80,50,20,20,1000,700);
};
console.src = 'res/console.png';

var hero = new Hero();
var prop;

var isPlaying = false;

window.onload = init;
var requestAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        function(callback) {
                            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                        };

function init() {
    console.debug('initializing...');

    document.addEventListener('keydown',keyDown,false);
    document.addEventListener('keyup',keyUp,false);

    ctxStage.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctxStage.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctxStage.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctxEntities.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctxEntities.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctxEntities.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

    prop = new Entity(consoleImg,20,20,80,50,0,0);

    startLoop();
}

function startLoop(){
    console.debug('starting loop...');
    isPlaying = true;
    loop();
}

function stopLoop(){
    console.debug('stopping loop...');
    isPlaying = false;
}

function loop(){
    if(isPlaying){
        requestAnimFrame(loop);
        draw();
        update();
    }
}

function update(){
    hero.update();
}

function clearCtx(){
    ctxEntities.clearRect(0,0,stage.width,stage.height);
}

function draw(){
    clearCtx();
    ctxEntities.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctxEntities.fillRect(0,0,stage.width,stage.height);
    ctxEntities.drawImage(bgImg,0,0,80,50,-200,-90,1000,700);
    hero.draw();
    prop.draw();
}


// hero class
function Hero() {
    this.xpos = 140;
    this.ypos = 320;
    this.srcX = 0;
    this.srcY = 0;
    this.width = 10;
    this.height = 20;
    this.scaleX = 50;
    this.scaleY = 80;
    this.isUpKey;
    this.isDownKey;
    this.isLeftKey;
    this.isRightKey;
    this.img = playerImg;

    this.speed = 2;
    this.defspeed = 3.5;
    this.dir = 'right';
}

Hero.prototype.draw = function() {
    ctxEntities.drawImage(this.img,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,this.xpos,this.ypos,this.scaleX,this.scaleY);
};

Hero.prototype.update = function() {
    this.checkKeys();

    if(this.dir == 'right'){
        if(this.scaleX >= 0){
            this.srcX = 0;
        }
        if(this.scaleX >= 40){
            this.scaleX = 40;
            this.speed = this.defspeed;
        }else{
            this.xpos -= 2.3;
            this.speed = 0;
            this.scaleX += 5;
        }
    }else if(this.dir =='left'){
        if(this.scaleX <= 0){
            this.srcX = 10;
        }
        if(this.scaleX <= -40){
            this.scaleX = -40;
            this.speed = this.defspeed;
        }else{
            this.xpos += 2.3;
            this.speed = 0;
            this.scaleX -= 5;
        }
    }
};

Hero.prototype.checkKeys = function() {
    if(this.isLeftKey){
        this.xpos += -this.speed;
        this.dir = 'left';
    }
    if(this.isRightKey){
        this.xpos += this.speed;
        this.dir = 'right';
    }
};
// end of hero class


// entity class
function Entity(img,xpos,ypos,width,height,scaleX,scaleY){
    this.img = img;
    this.xpos = xpos;
    this.ypos = ypos;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.scaleX = scaleX;
    this.scaleY = scaleY;
}

Entity.prototype.draw = function(){
    ctxEntities.drawImage(this.img,0,0,this.width,this.height,this.xpos,this.ypos,this.scaleX,this.scaleY);
};
// end of entity class


// input handling
function keyDown(e){
    var keyID = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if(keyID == 38 || keyID == 87){ //w
        e.preventDefault();
        hero.isUpKey = true;
    }
    if(keyID == 37 || keyID == 65){ //a
        e.preventDefault();
        hero.isLeftKey = true;
    }
    if(keyID == 40 || keyID == 83){ //s
       e.preventDefault();
       hero.isDownKey = true;
    }
    if(keyID == 39 || keyID == 68){ //d
        e.preventDefault();
        hero.isRightKey = true;
    }
}

function keyUp(e){
    var keyID = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if(keyID == 38 || keyID == 87){
        hero.isUpKey = false;
    }
    if(keyID == 37 || keyID == 65){
        hero.isLeftKey = false;
    }
    if(keyID == 40 || keyID == 83){
        hero.isDownKey = false;
    }
    if(keyID == 39 || keyID == 68){
        hero.isRightKey = false;
    }
}
// end of input handling
```

**UPDATE**
Half of my issue was fixed by markE. The only issue I currently have, is my entitiesCtx is the the only context that can draw images/rectangles. The other ctx's just can't draw anything. I updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using JS “classes” to draw on multiple canvas’s**

[I expanded my answer to include example of using your JS classes]

This example illustrates your 2 js-classes that draw images on canvases

- The **Entity class** controls and draws an image on a canvas.
- The **Hero class** controls and draws spritesheets on a canvas.

There is also an image loader so that all your images are fully loaded before they are used.

In your question you included only your js-class code and no specifics on your project.

So I made up my own project using your Hero and Entity classes (pardon my taking liberty).

This image shows your Entity and Hero classes in action drawing on all 3 of your canvases...

[image]

**This is the background canvas containing:**

- A sky-blue rect filling the canvas (the sky)
- The background contains 2 Entity class objects.
- A sun which is an image wrapped in an Entity class object
- A wall which is an image wrapped in an Entity class object

[image]

**This is the stage canvas containing:**

- A cannon which is an Entity class object that animates up and down

[image]

**This is the entities canvas containing:**

- A cat image is a spritesheet image wrapped in a Hero class object
- The cat object animates sprites in response to the cannon object
- The cat is composed of a spritesheet that’s controlled by the Hero class

[image]

**The Entity class controls and draws an image on a canvas:**

- The image can be moved and scaled.
- The Entity class has 3 methods.
- Entity.draw() will draw the image on the canva.
- Entity.set() will set the XY position of the image on the canvas.
- Entity.scale() will scale the image.

Here is the code for the Entity class:

```
// Entity class
function Entity(context,img,x,y){
    this.context=context;
    this.img = img;
    this.xpos = x;
    this.ypos = y;
    this.width = img.width;
    this.height = img.height;
    this.scaleX = img.width;
    this.scaleY = img.height;
}

// Entity.set()
Entity.prototype.set = function(x,y){
    this.xpos=x;
    this.ypos=y;
}

// Entity.scale()
Entity.prototype.scale = function(scaleX,scaleY){
    this.scaleX=scaleX;
    this.scaleY=scaleY;
}

// Entity.draw()
Entity.prototype.draw = function(){
    this.context.drawImage(this.img,
        0,0,this.width,this.height,
        this.xpos,this.ypos,this.scaleX,this.scaleY);
}
```

**The Hero class controls and draws spritesheets on a canvas**

- The individual sprites are pulled from the spritesheet image.
- Each sprite is defined by an object having its x,y,width,height within the spritesheet.
- The sprites can be moved and scaled.
- The Hero class has 3 methods.
- Hero.draw() will draw one of the sprites on the canvas.
- Hero.set() will set which sprite is drawn and its XY position on the canvas
- Hero.scale() will scale the sprite.

Here is the code for the Hero class:

```
// Hero class
function Hero(context,img,spriteDefs) {
    this.context=context;
    this.spriteDefs=spriteDefs;
    this.img = img;
    this.xpos = 0;
    this.ypos = 0;
    this.srcX = 0;
    this.srcY = 0;
    this.width = img.width;
    this.height = img.height;
    this.scaleX = img.width;
    this.scaleY = img.height;
    this.isUpKey;
    this.isDownKey;
    this.isLeftKey;
    this.isRightKey;

    this.speed = 2;
    this.defspeed = 3.5;
    this.dir = 'right';
}

// Hero.set()
Hero.prototype.set = function(spriteNumber,x,y){
    // pull the specified sprite
    var sprite=this.spriteDefs[spriteNumber];
    this.srcX=sprite.x;
    this.srcY=sprite.y;
    this.width=sprite.width;
    this.height=sprite.height;
    // default scale to 100%
    this.scaleX=sprite.width;
    this.scaleY=sprite.height;
    this.xpos=x;
    this.ypos=y;
}

// Hero.scale()
Hero.prototype.scale = function(scaleX,scaleY){
    this.scaleX=scaleX;
    this.scaleY=scaleY;
}

// Hero.draw()
Hero.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.context.drawImage(this.img,
        this.srcX,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,
        this.xpos,this.ypos,this.scaleX,this.scaleY);
}
```

**This is an image loader that makes sure all images are loaded before they are used**

```
var imageURLs=[];
var imagesOK=0;
var imgs=[];
imageURLs.push("cats.png");
imageURLs.push("cannonLifted.png");
imageURLs.push("brickwall.jpg");
imageURLs.push("sun.png");
loadAllImages();

function loadAllImages(){
    for (var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {
      var img = new Image();
      imgs.push(img);
      img.onload = function(){ imagesOK++; imagesAllLoaded(); };
      img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

var imagesAllLoaded = function() {
  if (imagesOK==imageURLs.length ) {
     // all images are fully loaded an ready to use
     cat=imgs[0];
     cannon=imgs[1];
     wall=imgs[2];
     sun=imgs[3];
     start();
  }
};
```

Here is complete code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/yCW9U/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px; }
    h3{ font-size:2em; }
    #wrapper{
        position:relative;
        width:350px;
        height:400px;
    }
    #bg,#stage,#entities{
        position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
        border:1px solid green;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
</style>

<script>
$(function(){


    //////////////////////////////
    // get context references
    //////////////////////////////


    // stage
    var stage = document.getElementById('stage');
    var ctxStage = stage.getContext('2d');
    // entities
    var entitiesStage = document.getElementById('entities');
    var ctxEntities = entitiesStage.getContext('2d');
    // background
    var bg = document.getElementById('bg');
    var ctxBg = bg.getContext('2d');


    //////////////////////////////
    // public variables
    //////////////////////////////


    // images
    var wall,cat,cannon,sun;

    // display objectx
    var sunEntity,wallEntity,cannonEntity,catHero;

    // animation vars 
    var cannonX=65;
    var cannonMove=-10;
    var cannonMin=75;
    var cannonMax=185;
    var cannonY=185;
    var cannonSafe=145;

    // cat hero sprites
    var catSpriteNames={
        laying:0,
        layingX:250,
        layingY:127,
        standing:1,
        standingX:165,
        standingY:25
    };
    var catSprites=[
        {x:80, y:30, width:67, height:48},
        {x:15, y:8,  width:47, height:78}
    ];


    //////////////////////////////
    // preload all images
    //////////////////////////////


    var imageURLs=[];
    var imagesOK=0;
    var imgs=[];
    imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/cats.png");
    imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/cannonLifted.png");
    imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/BrickWall.jpg");
    imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/sun.png");
    loadAllImages();

    function loadAllImages(){
        for (var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {
          var img = new Image();
          imgs.push(img);
          img.onload = function(){ imagesOK++; imagesAllLoaded(); };
          img.src = imageURLs[i];
        }      
    }

    var imagesAllLoaded = function() {
      if (imagesOK==imageURLs.length ) {
         // all images are fully loaded an ready to use
         cat=imgs[0];
         cannon=imgs[1];
         wall=imgs[2];
         sun=imgs[3];
         start();
      }
    };


    //////////////////////////////
    // build the display objects 
    // and start animation
    //////////////////////////////


    function start(){

        // static background (canvas: bg)
        // rectangle=blue sky
        ctxBg.rect(0,0,bg.width,bg.height);
        ctxBg.fillStyle="skyblue";
        ctxBg.fill();
        // sun image @ 75% scale
        sunEntity=new Entity(ctxBg,sun,185,15);
        sunEntity.set(25,15);
        sunEntity.scale(sun.width*.75,sun.height*.75);
        sunEntity.draw();
        // wall image
        wallEntity=new Entity(ctxBg,wall,250,bg.height-wall.height);
        wallEntity.set(250,bg.height-wall.height,wall.width,wall.height);
        wallEntity.draw();


        // stage (canvas: stage)
        // contents: wall
        cannonEntity=new Entity(ctxStage,cannon,cannonX,cannonY,cannon.width,cannon.height,cannon.width,cannon.height);
        cannonEntity.draw();


        // entities (canvas: entities)
        // contents: 
        catHero=new Hero(ctxEntities,cat,catSprites);
        catHero.set(catSpriteNames.laying,catSpriteNames.layingX,catSpriteNames.layingY);
        catHero.draw();

        animate();
    }

    function animate(){

        cannonY+=cannonMove;
        if(cannonY<cannonMin){ cannonY=cannonMin; cannonMove=-cannonMove; }
        if(cannonY>cannonMax){ cannonY=cannonMax; cannonMove=-cannonMove; }

        cannonEntity.context.clearRect(0,0,stage.width,stage.height);
        cannonEntity.set(cannonX,cannonY);
        cannonEntity.draw();

        if(cannonY>cannonSafe){
            catHero.set(catSpriteNames.laying,catSpriteNames.layingX,catSpriteNames.layingY);
        }else{
            catHero.set(catSpriteNames.standing,catSpriteNames.standingX,cannonY-50);
        }
        catHero.context.clearRect(0,0,entities.width,entities.height);
        catHero.draw()


        window.setTimeout(function(){animate();},500);
    }


    // Hero class
    function Hero(context,img,spriteDefs) {
        this.context=context;
        this.spriteDefs=spriteDefs;
        this.img = img;
        this.xpos = 0;
        this.ypos = 0;
        this.srcX = 0;
        this.srcY = 0;
        this.width = img.width;
        this.height = img.height;
        this.scaleX = img.width;
        this.scaleY = img.height;
        this.isUpKey;
        this.isDownKey;
        this.isLeftKey;
        this.isRightKey;

        this.speed = 2;
        this.defspeed = 3.5;
        this.dir = 'right';
    }
    // Hero.set()
    Hero.prototype.set = function(spriteNumber,x,y){
        // pull the specified sprite
        var sprite=this.spriteDefs[spriteNumber];
        this.srcX=sprite.x;
        this.srcY=sprite.y;
        this.width=sprite.width;
        this.height=sprite.height;
        // default scale to 100%
        this.scaleX=sprite.width;
        this.scaleY=sprite.height;
        this.xpos=x;
        this.ypos=y;
    }
    // Hero.scale()
    Hero.prototype.scale = function(scaleX,scaleY){
        this.scaleX=scaleX;
        this.scaleY=scaleY;
    }
    // Hero.draw()
    Hero.prototype.draw = function() {
        this.context.drawImage(this.img,
            this.srcX,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,
            this.xpos,this.ypos,this.scaleX,this.scaleY);
    }


    // Entity class
    function Entity(context,img,x,y){
        this.context=context;
        this.img = img;
        this.xpos = x;
        this.ypos = y;
        this.width = img.width;
        this.height = img.height;
        this.scaleX = img.width;
        this.scaleY = img.height;
    }
    // Entity.set()
    Entity.prototype.set = function(x,y){
        this.xpos=x;
        this.ypos=y;
    }
    // Entity.scale()
    Entity.prototype.scale = function(scaleX,scaleY){
        this.scaleX=scaleX;
        this.scaleY=scaleY;
    }
    // Entity.draw()
    Entity.prototype.draw = function(){
        this.context.drawImage(this.img,
            0,0,this.width,this.height,
            this.xpos,this.ypos,this.scaleX,this.scaleY);
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <h3>Watch out Kitty!</h3><br>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <canvas id="bg" width=350 height=400></canvas>
        <canvas id="stage" width=350 height=400></canvas>
        <canvas id="entities" width=350 height=400></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed half of the issue. The only problems left are that my ctxStage is still not drawing an image, and my prop(of the entity class) still isn't drawing. The html/css are bug free.

Comment: I added to my answer for an explanation about your images.  You must give your images time to load before trying to drawImage them.  To do this you can use image.onload.

Comment: I've almost got it! It's only drawing for a second. It works fine when I draw it with ctxEntities; ctxStage, however, cannot draw an Image, or a rectangle.

Comment: If this helps at all, you can see the project here. I'm currently drawing the background image and the rectangle with entitiesCtx. I want to draw it with the stageCtx. My prop object of Entity() still isn't drawing, either. https://c9.io/benjihansen/canvasgame/workspace/index.html

Comment: Make sure you use image.onload for the other images in your project also--all your images need time to load ;)

Comment: You've helped out a lot! I added the onload function to every image, but I'm not sure image loading is the issue here. My issue is that the only context that is drawing images/rectangles is my entitiesCtx. Thanks so much for your help! I would upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I replace my answer to show your Entity and Hero classes in action drawing on all 3 of your canvases.